# How can I check if string is in AAABBB or AABBAA or ABCABC or BBBAAA or BABABA or ABABAB or XXXXXA or AXXXXX format

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

How can I check if string is in AAABBB or AABBAA or BBBAAA or BABABA or ABABAB or XXXXXA or AXXXXX format in SQL server. (where 'A' is any character from A-Z... AAA means all characters are same... same for 'B')
I want to validate this string with such patterns. I tried using regular expressions. I tried many regular expressions but failed to get the result.

I tried something like this:

```
Select CASE WHEN 'AAABBB' LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' THEN 'Valid' ELSE 'Invalid' END
```

(Above regular expression is just for demo I need something there to validate my string). For every string I will be needing separate regular expression

I can validate string my comparing each character with others but it will increase size of my query.I need something short and simple.

Comment: I was getting into your question until I hit the part about `XXXXXA` or `AXXXXX`.  Can you show us clear input along with the expected output?

Comment: Also, SQL Server does not have particularly good built in regex support, apart from some very basic regex support with the `LIKE` operator, `PATINDEX`, and a few other places.  You may not be able to easily do what you have in mind.

Comment: SQL Server does not provide native support for regular expressions.  How did you test regular expressions?

Comment: Why does it take so long to answer the first comment here?

Comment: The question title also includes `ABCABC` as a pattern, though this isn't mentioned in the question text?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this . . . painfully.  Note that patterns such as ABABAB and BABABA are the same -- because the letters are interchangeable.

```
select v.str,
       (case when len(str) <> 6 then NULL
             when rep = '@@@%%%' then 'AAABBB'
             when rep = '@@%%@@' then 'AABBAA'
             when rep = '@%@%@%' then 'ABABAB'
             when str like '%' + a then 'XXXXXA'
             when str like a + '%' then 'AXXXXX'
       end) as match_pattern
from (values ('ABABAB')) v(str) cross apply
     (values (left(v.str, 1), left(replace(v.str, left(v.str, 1), ''), 1))) v2 (a, b) cross apply
     (values (replace(replace(v.str, a, '@'), b, '%'))) v3(rep);
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/OGK71779) is a rextester.

The idea is to find the values of "a" and "b" in the string.  "a" is the first letter in the string.  "b" is any other letter.  The rest is just replacement and checking against patterns.  The use of `'@'` and `'%'` is just to get letters that don't conflict with any characters already in the string.

Comment: I think you need to swap out `LENGTH` for `LEN`, and I get an error `Incorrect syntax near 'v2'`

Answer (score 0):

First: these are not regular expressions. SQL Server allows to match a single character with a specified range, but this is not remotely close to what is known as regular expressions.

You did not specify what the X represents. I will take it to mean a numerical character, but you can simply adapt the following to what you meant with it. The next query assumes a table `mytable` with a column `str` that needs its values to be tested:

```
select str,
       coalesce(
           case
           when upper(str) like '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' then
               case str
               when replicate(substring(str,1,2), 3) then 'Valid ABABAB'
               when replicate(substring(str,1,1), 2) 
                  + replicate(substring(str,3,1), 2) 
                  + replicate(substring(str,1,1), 2) then 'Valid AABBAA'
               when replicate(substring(str,1,1), 3) 
                  + replicate(substring(str,4,1), 3) then 'Valid AAABBB'
               end
           when str like '[A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' then 'Valid AXXXXX'
           when str like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Za-z]' then 'Valid XXXXXA'
           end, 
       'Invalid') as validation
from   mytable
```

There is a boundary case, where A and B happen to be the same character. In that case we actually have AAAAAA. The query above allows this. If this should not be allowed then just exclude that case with an extra condition in the outer `case`:

```
select str,
       coalesce(
           case
           when upper(str) like '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' 
                and str <> replicate(substring(str,1,1), 6) then
               case str
               when replicate(substring(str,1,2), 3) then 'Valid ABABAB'
               when replicate(substring(str,1,1), 2) 
                  + replicate(substring(str,3,1), 2) 
                  + replicate(substring(str,1,1), 2) then 'Valid AABBAA'
               when replicate(substring(str,1,1), 3) 
                  + replicate(substring(str,4,1), 3) then 'Valid AAABBB'
               end
           when str like '[A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' then 'Valid AXXXXX'
           when str like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Za-z]' then 'Valid XXXXXA'
           end, 
       'Invalid') as validation
from   mytable
```